# how to better use context in react

Tags: react-context

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const initDraw = {
    open: false,
    title: '',
    child: null,
    close: () => { }
}

const DrawContext = createContext(initDraw);

const draw = () => useContext(DrawContext);

export {
    DrawContext,
    draw,
}
```